# Flexible MySQL Database Schema to store logs

Tags: mysql, database-design, logging

I'm looking for a flexible MySQL database schema to save logs.

Currently I'm using this one (simplified for the example).

[image: Loggin]

Bigger version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6NC9.png

I can do a `select * from log`, get the log_type and read the specific table.
If log_type:tag is user, the specific table will be called log_user.

To add logs for an application I will add a tag application into `log_type` and
create a new table `log_application`.

To read all logs for a user, I do a select `SELECT * FROM log_user INNER JOIN log ON log_user.logid=log.id WHERE userid=123`.

This is actually working very well and flexible I would nevertheless be interested if somebody has a better idea for such a database schema.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need 3 tables to store logs.  Just use one flat table to achieve the same objective. This will save you from doing a lot of unnecessary coding.